# Python3 pkgutil get_data usage

Tags: python-3.x, package

I am trying to use `pkgutil.get_data` to get resource from a package.
I have read through the [documentation for this API](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) , where it said

> To use `pkgutil.get_data(package, resource)` ....  The `package` argument should be the name of a package, in **standard module format (`foo.bar`)**. The `resource` argument should be in the form of a relative filename, using / as the path separator.

I am confused to understand the terminology **standard module format (`foo.bar`)**. Let us say we have below example, and I want to get resource `collection_effects.csv`, how can I call this API ?

```
sound/                                            Top-level package
  __init__.py                                     Initialize the sound package
  effects/                                        Subpackage for sound effects
          __init__.py
          echo.py
          reverse.py
          cool_effects/
                      collection_effects.csv
          ...
```

From documentation, I think I could call the resource by :

```
import pkgutil
res = pkg.util.get_data("sound.effects", "/cool_effects/collection_effects.csv")
```

, 
however, it seems using below will also return a bytecode (From documentation, failed to get resource will return `None`):

`res = pkg.util.get_data("sound/effects", "/cool_effects/collection_effects.csv")`

I am confused on what **standard module format** means, and what is correct to call this API ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this solves your problem

```py
import pkgutil
res = pkgutil.get_data('sound.effects', 'cool_effects/collection_effects.csv')
```

And **standard module format** means what you use with `import`, so it requires `__init__.py` file. By e.g. you can add the `__init__.py` file to the `cool_effects` folder and then use this code, and it should works

```py
import pkgutil
res = pkgutil.get_data('sound.effects.cool_effects', 'collection_effects.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks to [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420), since Python 3.3 you don't need an `__init__.py` for a directory to be considered a package. So both the above examples work even without an `__init__.py`